# Hadoop WebHDFS move file Could not resolve host: sandbox.hortonworks.com

Tags: hadoop

So, I learn about hadoop. I use hortonworks sandbox. I tried to move a file from my local pc (test.txt) into the hadoop using WebHDFS.

To do something like that, I found out from [apache hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File) says that it need 2 steps. The first is sumbit PUT http request, and get the datanode information.

This is what I do:

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://127.0.0.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/root/learnhadoop/data/test.txt?user.name=root&op=CREATE"
```

This is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 17:26:10 GMT
Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 17:26:10 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 17:26:10 GMT
Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 17:26:10 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=u=root&p=root&t=simple&e=1427945170842&s=EY5ZvGuYx8WRYvNR2NbILuG14s0=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 02-Apr-2015 03:26:10 GMT; HttpOnly
Location: http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/root/learnhadoop/data/test.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=root&namenoderpcaddress=sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020&overwrite=false
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Then submit another PUT http request using the datanode url.

```
curl -i -X PUT -T test.txt "http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/webhdfs/v1/user/root/learnhadoop/data/test.txt?user.name=root&op=CREATE"
```

After that, nothings happen and error showing up. This is the error message:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

Do I miss something? What should I do to move my file into hadoop. Thanks in advance

Comment: you may want to replace `sandbox.hortonworks.com` by `127.0.0.1` at all places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the temporary fix would be replace `sandbox.hortonworks.com` by `127.0.0.1` at all places. Eventually, I guess the reason why NameNode replys Datanode location as `sandbox.hortonworks.com` is because the vm set its hostname as `sandbox.hortonworks.com`, so you can change the hostname back to `localhost` to resolve this problem completely.